# Fenchel conjugate of rank function

Tags: inequality, matrix-rank, trace, duality-theorems

In the [paper](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/rank_min_heur_sys_approx.pdf) I am reading, they find the conjugate of the rank function$(f)$ of a rectangular matrix $X$ with bounded spectral norm($\|X\| \leq 1$), as follows
$$
f^*(Y) = \sup_{\|X\|\leq 1} \operatorname{Tr}(X'Y)-f(X)
$$
Using Trace inequality $Tr(X'Y) \leq \sum_{i} \sigma_i(X) \sigma_i(Y)$, and letting $X = U_x\Sigma_xV_x$ and $Y = U_y\Sigma_yV_y$ athe SVD of $X$ and $Y$, the paper assumes $U_x = U_y, V_x = V_y$ since $f(X)$ is independent of $Ux_, V_x$ and writes the conjugate as
$$
f^*(Y) = \sup_{\|X\|\leq 1} \Sigma_i \sigma_i(X)\sigma_i(Y)-f(X)
$$

Two concepts in the above constructions are not clear to me,

1) How one defines the rank of a rectangular matrix ?.  Here it is assumed that $X$ is a rectangular matrix
2) Trace inequality says that equality holds only if the matrices are diagonalizable, and a rectangular matrix is not diagonalizable. In that case how can the equality in the final equation holds ?

Comment: It will be better if you put up the link to the paper.

Comment: @Hans this is the paper  https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/rank_min_heur_sys_approx.pdf